# How to print the name of the column with missing values and the count of missing values in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook, data-science

I tried this

```
print(housing.columns[housing.isnull().any()], housing.isnull().sum().sum())
```

and Got the following output:

```
Index(['total_bedrooms'], dtype='object') 207
```

But I'm trying to get the following output:

```
(total_bedrooms, 207 )
```

I believe there's a more intuitive way to get the answer I want than the way I did. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do in one line

```
[*df.isnull().sum().loc[lambda x : x>0].items()]
```